# Do flavoured coffee beans need to be brewed at a different temperature?

Tags: brewing-process, flavored-coffee, temperature

I have in the past seen flavoured whole coffee beans on sale. [Here](http://www.thebeanshack.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d2_FlavouredCoffee.html) is an example (though it was a roadside market stall where I saw them).

Do you need to brew the coffee at a lower temperature, or otherwise prepare it any differently than you would do with unflavoured beans?

Comment: The site you linked sells 'Expresso' grind. \**twitch**.

Comment: @Tom Haha, I didn't read that far. Feel free to replace with another site if you like :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes an unintentionally snarky answer:

Flavored coffee and high quality coffee are rarely synonymous. Since flavored coffee masks the organic and natural flavors of the coffee itself, it's rare that a quality bean is used in the first place. Imagine ordering a [Glenlivet 18](https://www.masterofmalt.com/whiskies/the-glenlivet-18-year-old-whisky/) with Pepsi.

Ergo, I'd say that your brew temperature with a flavored coffee isn't extremely important. In the end, you're really just going to be tasting artificial (natural if you're *lucky*) flavors that cover up the taste of the bad coffee underneath.

What I would say, however, is before you start using quality coffee after using flavored coffee, be sure to clean your equipment thoroughly. The flavors used in those coffees have a tendency to stick around long after they're gone.

Comment: I prefer to give the benefit of the doubt and hope that they aren't using horrible beans, just less expensive beans.  There is a local roaster around here that does mostly flavored coffee.  They also do some other blends that aren't horrible, but aren't fantastic either.  I've gotten some of their unflavored stock before, and it wasn't horrible, just not good.  It takes all kinds through.

Comment: @ChrisinAK Even still, I feel like the flavoring will mask any imperfections in your brewing process.

Comment: I agree.  I haven't drank flavored coffee in a long time and don't endorse it.  I'm just saying that the foundation isn't always as crumbly as many of us would like to believe.  There are roasters out there ruining perfectly mediocre beans with flavoring instead of making perfectly horrible beans even worse.